# Train Images Classifier - OTB Spatial reference of input and samples don't match

Tags: coordinate-system, classification, otb-applications

I am running the Train Images Classifier on OTB 7.1.0. I used QGIS to upload a raster images and then created a vector polygon file for my classes. I ensured that both the raster and vector files are in the same projected coordinate system. I checked both in R and QGIS. When I run the Train Images Classifier tool I receive an error (image 1). I look at both files coordinate system below the error, but they are an exact match (image 2). Image 3 contains the beginning of the analysis. Could anyone shed some light on this? Let me know if you need any additional information.

[image: Error Message]

[image: Spatial References for each file]

[image: Analysis log prior to error]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong with your CRSs.

This warning occurs because you have only 107 pixels of class #1, and the default behavior of the application is to collect (i) 1000 samples and (ii) the same number of samples per class.
You can see that the rate value for class #1 is 1.0, meaning that every pixels which are labeled as "class #1" are collected. Also, the number of samples is forced to match the lowest number of samples in all classes, i.e. 107 samples (which is the minimum number of samples available for each classes... for class #1).

You might to balance your terrain truth, adding many polygons for class #1.

If you can't at some point, you might do some data augmentation to try to reduce your dataset imbalance.
The *TrainImagesClassifier* application is nice because it realizes for you many steps automatically (typically, the following applications are called internally: *PolygonClassStatistics*->*SampleSelection*->*SampleExtraction*->*TrainVectorClassifier*).

However it can be interesting sometimes to decompose what's done in this application.
You can insert the data augmentation step running the following applications:

1. *PolygonClassStatistics*: compute stats of your terrain truth polygons
2. *SampleSelection*: select pixels locations (it uses stats computed in 1.)
3. *SampleExtraction*: extract pixels components at samples locations (from 2.)
4. *SampleAugmentation*: create synthetic samples from real ones
5. *TrainVectorClassifier*: train a classifier

Comment: I saw that warning as well and actually changed both of those values to first 100 then 10 then 1 and I would still receive the same warning and error. My colleague and I actually just figured it out. It has to do with the raster image not being in the correct CRS. I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

I used R to project the raster image into the proper UTM zone and that did the trick. I thought I would also need to project my shapefile into the same UTM zone, but when I put it into the "input vector data list" within the "train image classifier" tool, the "field containing the class integer label for supervision" was blank. I decided to try using my originally shapefile (not projected and checked in QGIS that it still matched with the raster) and it worked. No errors or warnings were presented in the log tab.